# Smallest subfield of extension field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

I recently encountered the following statement in my textbook.

[image]

I was wondering how we show that the image of the evaluation homomorphism is indeed the *smallest* subfield containing F and α.

Comment: What is $\phi_\alpha$? And what is $\operatorname{irr}$?

Comment: $ϕ_α$ is the evaluation homomorphism from F[x] into E. irr(α,F) is a unique (up to multiplication by units) irreducible polynomial of minimal degree in F[x] which has α as a zero. This exists because we are taking α algebraic over F.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $L$ is a subfield of $E$ containing $F$ and $\alpha$; we must show $L$ contains $\phi_\alpha[F[x]]$. But this is evident from the fact that the field contains $F$ and $\alpha$, and any element in $\phi_\alpha[F[x]]$ is just a bunch of elements from $F$ and $\alpha$ with multiplications and additions. Since any subfield $L$ containing $F$ and $\alpha$ must contain $\phi_\alpha[F[x]]$, the latter is the smallest subfield fulfilling these conditions.