# Does every possible field containing $F$ and $c$ contain $F(c)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am hoping to get clarification on what is meant when we say the field extension $F(c)$ is the 'smallest' field extension containing $F$ and $c$. The first version of this statement is as posed in the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763772/smallest-subfield-of-extension-field) question.

We go through the basic construction: we start with a field $F$, an extension, $E$ of $F$, and a point $c \in E$ that is algebraic over $F$. Then we define $\sigma_c : F[x] \rightarrow E$ where $\sigma_c(a(x)):= a(c)$. From this starting point we construct $F(c):= Range(\sigma_c)$, and show that this is a subfield of $E$ that contains both $F$ and $c$. This construction is fine, and I understand the statement and proof in the linked question. I.e. that $F(c)$ is the smallest *subfield of $E$* that contains both $F$ and $c$.

However, when the same construction is introduced in Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra, he concludes by saying "We have just seen that the range of $\sigma_c$ is a field. In fact, it is the smallest field containing $F$ and $c$...". He goes onto say "By the smallest field containing $F$ and $c$ we mean the field which contains $F$ and $c$ and *is contained in any other field containing $F$ and $c$*" (emphasis mine).

I am not sure if Pinter is making a stronger statement or if he means the same thing as above. I.e. I'm not sure whether he is saying for *any* field containing $F$ and $c$, not necessarily a subfield of $E$, that $F(c)$ is contained in that field. This is in contrast to $F(c)$ being the smallest *subfield of $E$ specifically*. **Is this stronger claim true?**

---

I believe this stronger claim isn't true, but I'm not sure. My reasoning is as follows: Consider now a different extension of $F$, $E_2$. Suppose $E_2$ also contains $c$, and $c$ is algebraic over $F$. However, suppose additionally that neither $E_2$ nor $E$ are subsets of one another. This necessarily means the field operations of $E_2$ and $E$ cannot be equal. Following the same construction, we may show that $F_2(c) := Range(\Sigma_c)$ is a subfield, but this time of $E_2$. Here $\Sigma_c: F[x] \rightarrow E_2$.

I know $F_2(c)$ is isomorphic to $F[x]/\langle q(x)\rangle$, where here $q(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $c$ that generates the ideal $Ker(\Sigma_c)$. The issue I see with the stronger claim is that we also have $F(c) \cong F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$, where now $p(x)$ is the minimum polynomial generating $Ker(\sigma_c)$. In each case, the kernel is the set of polynomials that have $c$ as a root in the respective fields $E$ and $E_2$.

But I don't see why these two kernels should contain the same polynomials: Since $E$ and $E_2$ have different field operations (we only know they agree over $F$), then it seems possible to me that there may be a polynomial $a(x) \in F[x]$ such that $$a_0 +_E (a_1 \cdot_E c) +_e ... +_E (a_n \cdot_E c^n) = 0$$ but $$a_0 +_{E_2} (a_1 \cdot_{E_2} c) +_{E_2} ... +_{E_2} (a_n \cdot_{E_2} c^n) \neq 0 $$ This would mean that the two ideals $\langle p(x)\rangle$ and $\langle q(x)\rangle$ are not equal, and hence we cannot always expect the quotient ring of $F[x]$ over them to be equal. This would then mean $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is not isomorphic to $F[x]/\langle q(x)\rangle$, and hence we have two subfields containing $F$ and $c$ that are both 'smallest' yet not equal.

I don't think  my argument is exactly correct, in particular where I claim there may be polynomials that disagree upon substitution of $c$. I'm also not sure about my claim that even when the kernels are different, that the induced quotient rings are not isomorphic is necessarily true.

Comment: The definition should be "the smallest subfield of $E$ which contains $F$ and $c$". I'm pretty sure this is also what the author means. This is the intersection of all subfields of $E$ which contain $F$ and $c$.

Comment: @Mark Thank you! I was leaning towards that being the case, but I wasn't quite sure as I think my justification for it being wrong was not water tight.